# Why ImageButton Display Text SubmitQuery Runtime

Tags: asp.net

i use imagebutton in datalist and set codeexpression :Eval("PictureUrl", "ProductImages\thumb_{0}") and runtime display submitquery.

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="pid" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                pname:
                <asp:Label ID="pnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pname") %>' />
                <br />
                pprice:
                <asp:Label ID="ppriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pprice") %>' />
                <br />
                publisher:
                <asp:Label ID="publisherLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("publisher") %>' />
                <br />
                writer:
                <asp:Label ID="writerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("writer") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton7" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PictureUrl", "ProductImages\thumb_{0}") %>' />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbpath %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [pname], [pprice], [PictureUrl], [gid], [storeid], [publisher], [writer], [pid] FROM [tblproduct]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

output one record:

```
pname:
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_pnameLabel_0">تکنیک عکاسی</span>
                <br />
                pprice:
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ppriceLabel_0">125000    </span>
                <br />
                publisher:
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_publisherLabel_0">اسرار دانش</span>
                <br />
                writer:
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_writerLabel_0">نصرالله کسرائیان</span>
                <br />
                <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DataList1$ctl00$ImageButton7" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ImageButton7_0" src="ProductImages%09humb_~/image/tecnikakasi.jpg" />
```

Comment: Show your code and output html

Comment: i edit myquestion,please check it

Comment: are you sure there is an image on "ProductImages%09humb_~/image/tecnikakasi.jpg" path?

Comment: im sure ~/image/tecnikakasi.jpg but i dont know ProductImages .

Comment: Then remove that word from your code. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You got the correct HTML rendered

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton7" runat="server" 

                ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PictureUrl", "ProductImages\thumb_{0}") %>' />
```

will produce `input` tag with `type=image`

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DataList1$ctl00$ImageButton7" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ImageButton7_0" src="ProductImages%09humb_~/image/tecnikakasi.jpg" />
```

The problem is `ProductImages%09humb_~/image/tecnikakasi.jpg` **not exists**. It may be wrong.

Check the relative path rendered.

Try

```
 ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PictureUrl", "~/ProductImages/thumb_{0}") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is displaying "SubmitQuery" because your image is not being loaded. If your writer alternate text, then alternate text will be displayed.

You can view source of the generated html and check the path of the image and try to correct it for resolving this problem.

ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PictureUrl", "{0}") %>'